# LLVM compiler 4.0 error when trying to build the app

Tags: objective-c, ios

> fatal error: UTF-16 (LE) byte order mark detected in
>   '/Users/Kylegreenlaw/Downloads/Sound +/Sound +/ViewController.m', but
>   encoding is not supported 1 error generated.

I was just in the .m file adding this

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressedWithSound:(id)sender {

    int randomSoundNumber = arc4random() % 4; //random number from 0 to 3

    NSLog(@"random NR = %i", randomSoundNumber);

    NSString *effectTitle;

    switch (randomSoundNumber) {
        case 0:
            effectTitle = @"Come at me BRO!";
            break;
        case 1:
            effectTitle = @"sound2";
            break;
        case 2:
            effectTitle = @"sound3";
            break;
        case 3:
            effectTitle = @"sound4";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    SystemSoundID soundID;

    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:effectTitle 
                                                          ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef)soundUrl, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Then I went to run it but the log printed this error. What happened, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Delete al the code in the method, and compile again - if the error goes away you have a bad character somewhere from copying code.  Delete line by line until you find the line with the bad character, and re-type it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have imported all the necessary files, you may have missed to import core audio or missed to link it to the project.